# Erlang: list flattening

Tags: erlang

I am newbie at Erlang, and I am trying to write some function which is going to return the following geometric progression for given `N ->  2, 4, .... 2^N`  as a list.
I have written some code:

```
-module(mymod).
-export([create_list/1]).

create_list(1) -> [2];
create_list(N) when N>1 ->
  lists:flatten([create_list(N-1)]++[trunc(math:pow(2, N))]).
```

It works fine till 29, but after I pass 30 and more it returns the same result:
`[2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,
 65536,131072,262144,524288,1048576,2097152,4194304,8388608,
 16777216,33554432,67108864,134217728,268435456,536870912|...]`

That is, only the first 29 terms. What to do to display fully?

Answer (score 3):

You can force the shell to print the entire result with `rp(create_list(30))`.

Answer (score 2):

Note the `[|...]` at the end of the displayed list. This means that it is just truncated after some length by the Erlang shell for pretty printing purposes.

One way to force printing the whole list is by calling `io:format("~p~n", [create_list(30)])`.

Answer (score 0):

or if you need unicode strings printed try io:format("~ts~n",[YourData]).